# Access files in ext4 partition created in different computer

Tags: permissions

I created lots of files and folder on a drive, formatted as ext4, on a machine with user name theuser. By default all files and folder are owned by that user and group. Now i change to use that drive on another machine with different user name. I can't access those files anymore. How can i access them without using chown and chgrp?

Comment: The username doesn't matter, the user ID does. Either you'll have to change the ownership of your files, or change your UID, or use a container to get a different UID.